# What does the ImageView method `setImageState(int[] state, boolean merge)` do?

Tags: android, imageview, imagebutton

There is no Reference documentation for the **`ImageView`** public method **`setImageState(int[] state, boolean merge)`**

- What does it do???
- How do I use it???
- What are the parameters `state` and `merge` for???

I want to use an ImageButton as an indicator in my app, with quite a few different images for different states. So I'm thinking this might be useful, but there's no information.

The following is from the source code for ImageView, but I'm none the wiser.

```
440     public void setImageState(int[] state, boolean merge) {
441         mState = state;
442         mMergeState = merge;
443         if (mDrawable != null) {
444             refreshDrawableState();
445             resizeFromDrawable();
446         }
447     }
```

Comment: see Drawable.setState()

Comment: @pskink Thanks. I'm guessing the boolean `merge` indicates whether the new set of states should be merged with the current existing states, or replace them. Though on second thoughts the source code doesn't seem to reflect this since there's no `if(merge) {}` type statement or similar.

Comment: see ImageView.onCreateDrawableState

Comment: @pskink I've posted an answer based on your suggested reading. Let me know if my logic is incorrect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pskink kindly pointed out that mMergeState from the **`ImageView`** method **`setImageState()`** shows up again in the  method **`onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace)`** shown below:

```
686     @Override
687     public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
688         if (mState == null) {
689             return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
690         } else if (!mMergeState) {
691             return mState;
692         } else {
693             return mergeDrawableStates(
694                     super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + mState.length), mState);
695         }
696     }
```

So it looks like if you set **`merge`** to false in **`setImageState(state, merge)`** then next time the view system calls **`onCreateDrawableState()`** it will return just the state you supplied in **`setImageState(state, merge)`**.
If however you set **`merge`** to true in **`setImageState(state, merge)`** then next time the view system calls **`onCreateDrawableState()`** it will return the existing state merged with the state you supplied in **`setImageState(state, merge)`**.

In other words, Yes the **`merge`** parameter determines whether the **`state`** you supply should be combined with or replace the current states of the ImageView next time the view system calls **`onCreateDrawableState()`**.

I still believe some explanation of the parameters should be added to the documentation. I've not come across any other public methods without any documentation so far.

Comment: I don't think the description of the `merge=true` path is quite right. It doesn't merge the new value with the _current_ state, but with the state determined by the superclass version of `onCreateDrawableState`. (`mergeDrawableStates` simply appends the second array into empty space at the end of the first.) So it seems like the use-case for the merge parameter is to add custom flags that you want to be sticky, or to force standard Drawable flags _on_.

Answer (score 1):

Simply it's method allow you set state of image with default states of system.

Say you have drawable xml definition of image, and you set to your imageView.setImageResource(id_your_drawable_xml)

you drawable xml has items with state focused

```
 <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true">
or
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true">
```

As we know ImageView from code directly we cannot set state focused (does not exists method setFocusedState), but you can do this by calling

```
myImageView.setImageState(View.FOCUSED,true) - with merge prev state like selected (set by setSelected(true))
```

it's will draw image with state focused